# Can an entity parent be modified in Google app engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, parent

When I update an entity, the entity needs to change parent, is there any way to do that?

Answer (score 8):

The clean way, and generally the only applicable one, is to make a new entity with the new parent and everything else copied, and delete the old one. Parents become part of an entity's key, so it's definitely NOT trivial to "change" that except by this kind of approach!